# How to fix wsdl file errors?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Dears

I trying to make and create web service, firstly i created the server side and wsdl file, but i get some errors in this wsdl file and i tried many time to solve it, i guess i should check the xmlns or xsd.

actually i'am  new in webwervices and don't now exactly how to investigate them, please advise me and let me know the error in my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:impl="http://DefaultNamespace" 
xmlns:intf="http://DefaultNamespace" 
xmlns:tns1="http://swing.javax" 
xmlns:tns2="http://awt.java"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://awt.java"/>
<import namespace="http://swing.javax"/>
```

The errors is

1. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns1:JPasswordField' to a(n) 'type definition' component. ImbCal.wsdl /SSPtest/WebContent/wsdl    line 196    WSDL Problem
2. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns2:List' to a(n) 'type definition' component.   ImbCal.wsdl /SSPtest/WebContent/wsdl    line 171    WSDL Problem
3. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .  ImbCal.wsdl /SSPtest/WebContent/wsdl    line 7  WSDL Problem
4. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .  ImbCal.wsdl /SSPtest/WebContent/wsdl    line 8  WSDL Problem

here one of elements

```
<element name="dbSelect">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="sql" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="level" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="mat_sel2" type="tns2:List"/>
      <element name="mymaterial" type="tns2:List"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
```

Comment: Validate your WSDL file using a tool like Altova XML Spy. Ensure all the imported XSDs are available in the correct locations. Have you generated WSDL from code or generated Code from wsdl?

Comment: I generate WSDL from code, " and the code contained some method witch not supported in WSDL.

Thank you a lot

Comment: How did you solve this? Can you please explain, because I'm facing the same issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I was trying to create the service for full code, which  contains more than one method and java parameters which is not applicable to be web service.

To solve that issue i did below steps:
1. make sure i doing the service for one method (That will give the needed result).
2. Change all java parameters that will not will work with the WebService.
3. make sure that the code doesn't cotains any Java Swing or ADT components because it'll make such these errors.

I hope my ans ware will solve the issue 

Good luck ;)

Comment: I checked my code it seems like everything is fine, not able to figure out the exact problem. Could you please provide changes you have done to fix the issue. Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code, i just edit the wrong from the code and regenerate the wsdll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:impl="http://DefaultNamespace" 
xmlns:intf="http://DefaultNamespace" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema">
<element name="main">
<complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="arg" type="xsd:string"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="mainResponse">
<complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="mainReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
 </element>
 <element name="finalmaterial">
 <complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="Couresn" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="IDL" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="Myco2" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="userlevel" type="xsd:int"/>
  <element name="LevelL" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
  </complexType>
  </element>
  <element name="finalmaterialResponse">
  <complexType>
  <sequence>
  <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="finalmaterialReturn" 
  type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
  </complexType>
  </element>
  </schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="finalmaterialRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:finalmaterial" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="finalmaterialResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:finalmaterialResponse" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="mainRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:main" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="mainResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:mainResponse" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ImbCal">
  <wsdl:operation name="main">
     <wsdl:input message="impl:mainRequest" name="mainRequest">
   </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output message="impl:mainResponse" name="mainResponse">
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="finalmaterial">
     <wsdl:input message="impl:finalmaterialRequest" 
   name="finalmaterialRequest">
   </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output message="impl:finalmaterialResponse" 
   name="finalmaterialResponse">
   </wsdl:output>
   </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ImbCalSoapBinding" type="impl:ImbCal">
   <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" 
   transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   <wsdl:operation name="main">
     <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
     <wsdl:input name="mainRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output name="mainResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
     </wsdl:operation>
     <wsdl:operation name="finalmaterial">
     <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
     <wsdl:input name="finalmaterialRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="finalmaterialResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
     </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="ImbCalService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:ImbCalSoapBinding" name="ImbCal">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/SSPwebservice
      /services/ImbCal"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
      </wsdl:definitions>
```